# .htacess to perform rewrite if file does not exist

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have two separate .htaccess files that I'd like to be fused together so that the first rewrite always takes precedence, which redirects some traffic to https base which domain. Then if the file at the url does not exist, then it sends the traffic to a php file. It is a url shortener, but if that returns at 404, then it shows a 404 error page.

Here are the bits and pieces of the .htaccess files:

This, below, I believe should redirect all http traffic except kore.tt and korett.com to https:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(kore\.tt|korett\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

This is something from the url shortener that is supposed to send traffic that doesn't exist to loader.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /loader.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But then if that returns a 404 error. Then this is the simple 404 error catch.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Comment: Your `ErrorDocument 404` will never execute because your rewrite rule is forwarding all non-files & non-directories to `loader.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a condition in your htaccess. There are many more ways to create rules. See if this can work for you.

```
  #check to see if loader.php exists on the filesystem, then do rewrite
  <If "-f %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} . '/loader.php'">
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^.*$ /loader.php [L]
  </If>
   #otherwise redirect to 404 page
  <Else>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^ /404.html [R=404,L]
  </Else>
```

Comment: But the OP wants a 404 page to be returned when the URL shortener (ie. `loader.php`) fails to find the file. (This would need to be generated from `loader.php`, not in `.htaccess`.) If you simply want the 404 `ErrorDocument` to be returned when `loader.php` does not exist then you wouldn't have to do anything - the OPs code should work as-is.

Comment: Maybe misunderstood. The way he worded it I took it that if loader.php doesn't exist then do a 404. I haven't tested the code but it would seem like it would create a redirect loop because of the rewrites redirecting non existing files to a non existent file if loader.php was missing.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct about the rewrite loop with the OP's code if `/loader.php` does not exist. However, this rewrite loop could be avoided in this example by simply removing the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _susbstitution_. ie. `loader.php` instead of `/loader.php`. mod_rewrite is then able to detect that the request is being rewritten to itself and prevents further rewrites, allowing the error document to be served.