# htaccess rewrite rule if file exists else go to PHP file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` that redirects all traffic except one domain to https. Then if the file it is trying to go to does not exist, then run the last block that follows, going to `loader.php`, but if the file goes exist go to it.

Here's one of the iterations I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(korle\.tt) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
<If "-f %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} . '/'">
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^.*$ /loader.php [L]
</If>
<Else>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ /404.html [R=404,L]
</Else>
```

What I am trying to do is if the user goes to `korlett.org` or `korlett.net` or `korelett.com` or any file within, it redirects to `https://`. But not `http://korle.tt` or other domains pointing to this dir (for now not specified), they'll stay HTTP.

Then after that, if the file does not exist or if the URL returns a 404 then run this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /loader.php [L]
```

Comment: What is the `<If` doing there? Normally you do this without that.

Comment: @tadman I thought so, but someone recommended I do that to check if the file returns a 404/not found. But when I try to validate the file, it says this isn't valid syntax (at the If). So I guess it doesn't matter if it works. Any suggestions?

Comment: The `RewriteCond` directive is a sort of `if` in and of itself. The other stuff is just in the way here.

Comment: What is `<If "-f %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} . '/'">` supposed to be doing?

Comment: From your description in this question, the code from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671982/htacess-to-perform-rewrite-if-file-does-not-exist) would work just fine. However, in your other question, you mentioned that `loader.php` was a URL shortener and appeared to say that if the URL shortener itself (ie. `loader.php`) failed to find the URL then serve a 404. Is this really the case? Also, what version of Apache are you using? How are you "validating" the file? `<If>` construct is only available from version 2.4.

Comment: @MrWhite The reason I posted a second question was because it seemed like what I said was misinterpreted. It should serve a 404 if loader.php isn't found, it should if anything is not found. But loader.php is a URL shortener that pairs "directories" with their long urls. What I'm looking to do with the htaccess file is first check if dir or file is an actual file, then if not sent it to loader.php to check if there is a long url pairs with that fragment/"dir" and if that fails then serve a 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then if not sent it to loader.php to check if there is a long url pairs with that fragment/"dir" and if that fails then serve a 404 page.

This 404 response would need to be managed by `loader.php` - ie. in your PHP script. Because once the request has been passed to `loader.php` (any request that does not map to a file or directory) then `.htaccess` has effectively finished with the request and you can no longer get Apache to handle the 404 response.

> It should serve a 404 if loader.php isn't found

However, this can indeed be managed in `.htaccess`, by setting an `ErrorDocument` and removing the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (which was probably the intention anyway, since you have included a `RewriteBase` directive). Removing the slash prefix prevents a rewrite loop (from repeatedly rewriting to `loader.php`). In other words, instead of this:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /loader.php [L]
```

It should be this:

```
RewriteRule ^ loader.php [L]
```

The regex `^` has the same net result as `^.*$` in this example, and simply serves to match *anything* (like you have in your HTTP to HTTPS redirect).

This prevents a rewrite loop because when rewriting to `loader.php` (relative path, no slash prefix) the rewrite engine detects that you are rewriting to the same URL and prevents further rewrites. Allowing the Apache 404 `ErrorDocument` to be served. (Whereas `/loader.php` is technically a different URL - as far as mod_rewrite is concerned - so the rewriting would continue.)

So, your complete `.htaccess` file becomes:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(korle\.tt) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ loader.php [L]
```

Another way to prevent a rewrite loop is to include a specific exception for `loader.php`. In fact, this can be used together with the above, in order to make the rewrite fail early, rather than waiting for the rewrite engine to detect the no-change. For example, change the last block above to read:

```
RewriteRule ^loader\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ loader.php [L]
```

Comment: `ErrorDocument 404` will never be invoked.

Comment: @anubhava The `ErrorDocument 404` is only for when `loader.php` itself does not exist. Providing measures are taken to avoid a rewrite loop, the custom error document does appear to get served OK in this scenario. (A sort-of dual purpose `.htaccess` file it would seem - although these directives should arguably be removed if `loader.php` is not present, but I guess this avoids having to edit the `.htaccess` file?)